# How to substract or sum data and store the values automatically?

Tags: sql, vb.net, mariadb

i have a table named `transaction`.
acc_type are the types of transactions that exist.

```
income account = 101,102,103,104,105,106
outcome account = 111,112,113,114,115,116
```

In the example table below 101 is income and 111 is the Outcome.

```
___________________________________________
|id|mem_id|name|date    |acc_type|amount   |
-------------------------------------------|
| 1|m01   |A   |1/6/2020|101     |150      |
| 2|m01   |A   |2/6/2020|101     |200      |
| 3|m01   |A   |3/6/2020|111     |100      |
| 4|m02   |B   |3/6/2020|101     |150      |
| 5|m02   |B   |3/6/2020|111     | 50      |
| 6|m02   |B   |4/6/2020|101     |100      |
| 7|m03   |C   |4/6/2020|102     |500      |
| 8|m03   |C   |5/6/2020|112     | 50      |
| 9|m03   |C   |5/6/2020|112     |100      |
--------------------------------------------
```

So, if the data has the same `mem_id` and  `acc_type` = 101 will be aggregated. But if `acc_type` 111 will be substracted.

it is possible to create an up to date balance table like this :

```
_______________________________________________________
|id|mem_id|name|date    |acc_type|amount   |balance    |
-------------------------------------------|------------
| 1|m01   |A   |1/6/2020|101     |150      |150        |
| 2|m01   |A   |2/6/2020|101     |200      |350        |
| 3|m01   |A   |3/6/2020|111     |100      |250        |
| 4|m02   |B   |3/6/2020|101     |150      |150        |
| 5|m02   |B   |3/6/2020|111     | 50      |100        |
| 6|m02   |B   |4/6/2020|101     |100      |200        |
| 7|m03   |C   |4/6/2020|102     |500      |500        |
| 8|m03   |C   |5/6/2020|112     | 50      |450        |
| 9|m03   |C   |5/6/2020|112     |100      |350        |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

if yes,what is the best method to applied(is it view, trigger, procedure or transact?). I need this balance table especially the balance value of every account type for each member.

i'm using 10.4.6-MariaDB and vb.net for the interface
thanks.

Comment: In the first case, it seems you want to do an _update_, while in the second case, it looks like you want an _insert_.  Please clarify what you are trying to do here.

Comment: i want to get an up to date balance amount  of every member with the same `mem_id` and `acc_id` everytime the transaction table got inserted or updated, and store it.

Comment: is it grouped by mem_id, or mem_id and name? or name is just a description of mem_id?

Comment: seems like the balance table is for information purpose only. Just use a View.

Comment: @HamdaniRizki . . . You seem to want insert/update/delete triggers on the `transactions` table to maintain the `balances` table.

Comment: How do you handle the insert/update/view? Using plain query in sql tool (e.g. SQLyog etc.) or using app that you build from e.g. PHP etc.?

Comment: I've been updating my questions